# EJB 3 Edit database record

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have problem with updating a database record using EJB and JPA. Persistence provider: `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`

When I am creating a record I am using this method:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

All is ok. Now I want to edit the the same record. For e.g. I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATION")
public class Operation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "OPERATION_AUTHOR")
    private String operationAuthor;

    @Column(name = "OPERATION_TYPE")
    private String operationType;

    @Column(name = "OPERATION_STATUS")
    private String operationStatus;

    @Column(name = "CREATED")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created;

    @Column(name = "COMPLETED")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date completed;  

    //Getters and setters
}
```

For e.g. I want to update only `operationStatus`. I am creating an entity, setting to it the same record id and new `operationStatus`. For updating I am using this method:

```
public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

The problem is when I update the record the status is updated correctly but all the other columns' values are set to `null` not left as they were before. I want to update only `operationStatus` and left other values untouched. Is this possible to do this using EJB? And what should I change to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the entity first, using Operation op = getEntityManager().find(Operation.class,id). Then do the op.setOperationStatus(value). That's all, it will get updated on session flush/close.

Comment: How didn'nt I think of it my self.. Must be my head not working for programming all day :/. Thanks that worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that calling entityManager.merge(entity) will update the db row (corresponding to the ID you set on the object)  with the same exact values that populate the java object (i.e., everything except status and id are null). You need to get the object out of the database and then update it.

A better option for this may be the following method:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param id - the ID of the entity to update
 * @param operationStatus - the status to apply
 */
public void setOperationStatus(long id, String operationStatus){
    Operation o = getEntityManager().find(Operation.class,id);
    o.setOperationStatus(operationStatus);
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```